# Displaying fields from geodata service using c#

Tags: arcgis-server, c#

I want to display my geodata stored in ArcGIS Server.
I did the connection to the server but the problem is the parameter `versionName`.  I will not use ArcSDE so I have ignored `versionName`.

Can someone help me to find the solution?

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.GISClient.IAGSServerObject so = GetSelectedServerProxy();

ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IGeoDataServer gdso = (ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IGeoDataServer)so;

//++ Queries for subfields if the Get Fields checkbox is enabled
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter qf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();

qf.WhereClause = "";

//++ based on the start index and count entered.
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IResultPortionInfo range = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ResultPortionInfoClass();
        range.StartIndex = 0;
        range.Count = 500;
    
//++ Run a tablesearch based on the version, table name, fields selected, startindex and count
ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseDistributed.IGDSQueryResultPortion res = gdso.TableSearch(versionName,"tabl", qf, range);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation you don't need to specify the version name on non-ArcSDE data: "If the geodatabase referenced by the GeoDataServer is an ArcSDE geodatabase, then you can set the versionName  parameter to the version on which to execute the query. If no versionName is provided, the version that the GeoDataServer is currently referencing is used. For non-ArcSDE geodatabases, the versionName is ignored."
See: [IGeoDataServer.TableSearch Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/TableSearch_Method/002600000089000000/)

Comment: thx for ur response but i don't know how to indicate that the versionName is ignored, what can in write in the property versionName

Comment: Have you tried to use: null

Comment: yes i tried but no result

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me with a geodataservice based on a file gdb.

```
private static void ListFields(string svcName)
{
    var conn =  new ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.AGS.AGSServerConnection();
    conn.Host = "localhost";
    conn.Connect();

    var ctx = conn.ServerObjectManager.CreateServerContext(svcName, "GeoDataServer");
    var gds = ctx.ServerObject as IGeoDataServer;
    var bo = ctx.CreateObject("esriGeodatabase.DEBrowseOptions") as IDEBrowseOptions;
    bo.ExpandType = esriDEExpandType.esriDEExpandDescendants;
    bo.RetrieveFullProperties = true;
    var elements = gds.get_DataElements(bo);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        var de = elements.get_Element(i);
        var deTable = de as IDETable;
        if (deTable != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", de.Name);
            for (int j = 0; j < deTable.Fields.FieldCount; j++)
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",deTable.Fields.get_Field(j).Name);
        }
    }
    ctx.ReleaseContext();
}
```

Comment: @kirkir Kuykendall thx for ur response but i have a problem with                                                                   `var ctx = conn.ServerObjectManager.CreateServerContext("servicename", "GeoDataServer");`

Comment: @hana "Have a problem" covers a lot of ground.  What, *specifically,* is the problem?

Comment: i can't connect to the arcgis server whith `ServerObjectManager.CreateServerContext` i receive this error message _Object reference not set to an instance of an object._